# Codeigniter Get difference of two dates

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, date, model

I need to get the difference of two dates and update the difference of the dates in the database.

**model**

```
public function approve($id, $leave_type, $leave_start, $leave_end) 
{   
    $diffDays= abs($leave_end - $leave_start);  
    $this->db->set('leave_days', $diffDays);
    $this->db->set('status', Approved);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('leave');

    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;  
}
```

abs($leave_end - $leave_start);  is not working. But when a hardcoded value is set to diffDays it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the date format to the format you are using.

```
    $leave_start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $leave_start);
    $leave_end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $leave_end);
    $diffDays = $leave_end->diff($leave_start)->format("%a");

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('leave', array('leave_days' => $diffDays));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try this for getting a difference between two dates.


    $date1=date_create($leave_start);
    $date2=date_create($leave_end);
    $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
    $days=$diff->format("%a");



    $id = 1;
    $this->db->set('leave_days', $days);

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('leave');
```

Comment: what? days are not got it.

Comment: Please describe more about your problem.

Comment: In my code above the status is set correctly but the diffDays is not set. I updated my above code. When I give a definite number for diffDays it works. But here 'abs($leave_end - $leave_start);  ' is not working.

Comment: you have only update date difference in DB so why are you using this abs() function in your code.

Comment: Is there any other alternative to get the difference of dates other than abs() function

Comment: in my answer have a solution to your problem.please try it

Comment: I tried that one also. But the database is still not updatinf.

Comment: INSERT INTO `leave` (`id`, `user_name`, `user_id`, `leave_type`, `leave_start`, `leave_end`, `leave_days`, `status`) VALUES
(121, 'Harry Potter', 6, 'Casual', '2018-06-28', '2018-06-29', 0, 'Approved'),
(122, 'Harry Potter', 6, 'Annual', '2018-06-22', '2018-06-25', 0, 'Approved'),
(123, 'Harry Potter', 6, 'Casual', '2018-06-23', '2018-06-25', 4, 'Approved');

Comment: sorry, but this is not your table structure and for getting the table structure please run this query in your phpmyadmin.

desc leave;

Comment: CREATE TABLE `leave` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` text NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `leave_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `leave_start` date NOT NULL,
  `leave_end` date NOT NULL,
  `leave_days` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: please try this  $this->db->set('leave_days', (int)$days);

Answer (score 0):

$leave_start = '01-01-2018';
$leave_end = '10-01-2018';

```
$id = 1;
$diffDays = abs($leave_end - $leave_start);     
$this->db->set('leave_days', $diffDays);

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('leave');
```

make sure that your $diffDays has some value because it worked for me.

Comment: Have you printed your variable "$diffDays" ,I think it has empty value ?